# Firebase Functions Deployment Failure

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am not able to deploy my app into production. I only have firebase hosting and functions. On `firebase serve` everything works well.

I obtain the following error:

```
    i  deploying functions, hosting        
    i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
    i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
    +  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
    +  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
    i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
    i  functions: packaged functions (46.72 KB) for uploading
    +  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
    i  hosting[library-app-d49fe]: beginning deploy...
    i  hosting[library-app-d49fe]: found 19 files in public
    +  hosting[library-app-d49fe]: file upload complete
    i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function app(us-central1)...
    !  functions[app(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
    Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs
    
    
    Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
            app
    
    
    To try redeploying those functions, run:
        firebase deploy --only "functions:app"
    
    
    To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
        firebase deploy --except functions
```

My `firebase.json` looks like this

```
    {
        "hosting": {
            "public": "public",
            "rewrites": [{
                "source": "**",
                "function": "app"
            }],
            "ignore": [
                "firebase.json",
                "**/.*",
                "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
        }
    }
```

and my `app.js` in functions folder has the following export:
`exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);`

I am sorry if I don't provide the necessary details but I am clueless of what the issue might be.

Comment: Could you also add a minimum reproducible **code** for your Cloud Function? Were you deploying the function running `firebase deploy --only "functions:app"` command? Was there anything you could see in the function **logs** mentioned in the error?

Comment: @DenisT. I seem to have fixed it. I added ```firebase.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)``` on my app,js and the deployment of all the app passed.